# NSNumbers in stored array disappear

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, retain, nsnumber

So I stored an NSMutableArray of NSNumber objects into the file "times.plist" then I load it and retain it on launch and the NSLog shows the correct value, but later the [times count] equals 0. Why are the NSNumbers disappearing?

```
times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:time],nil];
...

[times writeToFile:@"times.plist" atomically:YES];
...

times = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"times.plist"] retain];
NSLog(@"%f",[[times objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]);
```

Comment: Hard to say from the given code, but most likely you are assigning a new array to `times` somewhere between the point where you know it has the right content and the point where it is empty. Or you might be calling `[times removeAllObjects]` instead, but that seems slightly more like something you'd notice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay DUMB DUMB DUMB. Never do what I did. in my -init; method i had already initiated my times array with the code:

```
times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

and I was trying to restore them with:

```
times = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"times.plist"] retain];
```

BUT I was restoring it BEFORE I was initiating it and that erased it every time. Learn from my mistake and check the order of your -init; methods. ALWAYS.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to initialize it using `initWithObjects` if you're going to use `arrayWithContentsOfFile`.